Transpose the values of 1 column of a dataset depending on the value of another column
I have a Excel dataset with two columns; Column A is my reference column that has values which repeat, and Column B which has values I would like to transpose.
Want to go from this:



Column A
Column B




Apple
Value 1


Banana
Value 2


Cherry
Value 3


Apple
Value 4


Banana
Value 5


Grape
Value 6


Nuts
Value 7


Apple
Value 8



To this:



Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D




Apple
Value 1
Value 4
Value 8


Banana
Value 2
Value 5



Cherry
Value 3




Grapes
Value 6




Nuts
Value 7





I tried a VLOOKUP function, but it didn't provide me with a solution. I also tried to look for a solution but perhaps I am not using the right keywords.
Is there a basic formula that I am just missing here?
Any help would be greatly appreciated or at least pointing me to the appropriate thread with the solution.
Thank you.

This has a solution look here
